# C++ - Movimento no eixo do X (animação) - OpenGL

Tags: c++, animação, opengl

Tenho estado a tentar fazer uma simples animação no eixo do x, em que tenho uma cadeira e tenho ela desenhada por vários cubos, e em todos esses cubos pretendo mover a variável do x deles, para que eles se mexam nesse sentido.

Ele já se está a mexer o que acontece é que tenho de fazer algum tipo de iteração com o teclado ou com o rato para que ele se mexa. Tal como acontece da **Imagem Inicial** para a **Imagem Após Movimento**. Eu queria que isto acontecesse, mas sem ser necessário algum tipo de iteração por parte do utilizador.

Quando a cadeira chega perto da mesa ela atinge a coordenada limite, e tem de voltar para traz, o que acontece é que ela recua uma vez 0.05, e depois desaparece, tal como está na **Imagem Final**.

**Imagem Inicial:**
[image: Primeira Parte]
**Imagem Após Movimento:**
[image: Segunda Parte]
**Imagem Final:**
[image: Terceira Parte]

**Código que fiz para a cadeira fazer esta animação:**

```
float animation()
{
    //glFlush();
    for(;varX < 1;)
    {
            varX += 0.05;
            return varX;
    }

    if (varX >= 1)
    {
        for(;varX == 0;)
        {
            returnPosition();
            return varX;
        }
    }
    //glutPostRedisplay();

    /*
    do
    {
        varX += 0.05;
        return varX;
    }while(varX < 1);
    */
}

float returnPosition()
{
    //glFlush();
     for(;varX != 0;)
    {
            if(varX < 0)
            {
                for(;varX == 0;)
                {
                    varX += 0.05;
                    return varX;
                }

            }
            if(varX > 0)
            {
                for(;varX == 0;)
                {
                    varX -= 0.05;
                    return varX;
                }
            }
    }
    //glutPostRedisplay();
}
```

**Estás funções estão a ser chamadas na seguinte função:**

```
void display(void)
{

    glClear (GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);
    glColor3f (0.32, 0.32, 0.32); // Achei esta cor RGB em: http://www.rapidtables.com/web/color/RGB_Color.htm
    glLoadIdentity ();
    gluLookAt (0.0, 0.0, 5.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0, 0.0);


    glTranslatef(0.0, 0.0, zoom /*zoom*/);
    glRotatef(rotateX, 2.0, 0.0, 0.0);
    glRotatef(rotateY, 0.0, 2.0, 0.0);
    glRotatef(rotateZ, 0.0, 0.0, 2.0);

    anim = animation();


    chair(0, 0, 0, anim);
    chair(0, 0, 1, 0);
    table(0.05, 0.05, 0.05);

    glFlush ();

}
```

---

> Se alguém souber como me ajudar de maneira a que eu não precise de
>   interagir e a animação aconteça na mesma agradecia. Se alguém souber
>   como poderei fazer para que a cadeira não desapareça no final da
>   animação, também ficaria agradecido.

*Cumprimentos e Obrigado.*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Analisando seu código, me parece que você não está desenhando o código ao mudar os valores do `eixo X`, toda vez que você mudar o valor do eixo X, você precisa chamar o `glFlush()`, então no seu caso, a mudança ocorre apenas em memória, e apenas na última posição que você calcula é que é executado o `glFlush()`

Dica: Você está utilizando uma versão muito antiga do `OpenGL` que não é recomendada o uso, procure pesquisar um pouco sobre OpenGL profile core, ou `OpenGL programmable pipeline`

Comment: Eu precisei mesmo de fazer nesta versão, visto que foi isso que me foi pedido, entretanto até ja acabei o projecto e já resolvi este problema e a sua resolução de facto passava atravez de acrescentar alguns glFlush () .